# Do batch requests for the YouTube Data API work?

Tags: youtube-api, batch-processing, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I send a request to https://www.googleapis.com/batch/youtube/v3, but I get a 404 anyway. Perhaps I am sending the request incorrectly, but most likely the endpoint is not working.

As well as, I use Postman to test with next creds:

**1.** POST request to https://www.googleapis.com/batch/youtube/v3.

**2.** Set "Content-type" header to multipart/mixed.

**3.** Add raw text body with as HTTP:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=2222222&key=* HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8


GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=1111111&key=* HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Any suggestions for NodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube Data API version 3 does support [batch processing](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#march-11,-2015) only of the following form:

> [Batch processing](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_batch_processing) – The v3 API supports one of the batch processing use cases that the v2 API had supported. The v3 API's [`channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id), [`channelSections.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/list#id), [`guideCategories.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list#id), [`playlistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#id), [`playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#id), [`subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#id), [`videoCategories.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#id), and [`videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) methods all support an id parameter, which can be used to specify a comma-delimited list of IDs (video IDs, channel IDs, etc.). Using those methods, you can retrieve a list of multiple resources with a single request.

---

According to the docs, in case of [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, you're able to batch several calls, since, the `id` property accepts multiple channel IDs in one go:

> [**id**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) (string)
> The `id` parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube channel ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a `channel` resource, the `id` property specifies the channel's YouTube channel ID.

---

Note that the API provided me with the following response when asking the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint to produce info for 64 videos in one go (even only 51 produced the same response):

`ERROR 400: Bad Request`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.",
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "invalidFilters",
        "location": "parameters.",
        "locationType": "other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Therefore this API endpoint *does not accept more than 50 IDs*. It's very much presumable that the others will function the same way.

Comment: What if I need to send a request with 3 subrequests inside as batch with maxResults=50 on each, so in total there will be 150 channels in response per ONE request? Is it possible?

Comment: So "Batch processing" is currently working with limit 50?